Why is the uniqueness theorem for 1st order differential equations involve taking a partial dervative?
I'm looking for intuition on why the uniqueness theorem for 1st order differential equations on initial value problems involves looking at a partial derivative. Say f(x,y), the theorem  says if f is continuous and $f_y$ is continuous, then the solution through some open rectangle containing the initial point is unique.
How does $f_y$ being continuous play a role in uniqueness?

Have you seen a proof?

@ultralegend5385 the proof seems rather complicated, I am wondering if there is any easy intuition about it.

It comes (naturally) when trying to prove that the (naturally defined) sequence of functions converges uniformly to the required function. Are you having trouble with parts of the proof, or the idea of the proof?

Let $f:\Omega \subset \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$, $x'(t) = f(t,x)$ with initial condition $(t_{0},x_{0})$. For Picard-Lindelöf theorem it is needed $f(t,x)$ to be Lipschitz with respect to $x$ in $\Omega$. The proof of this theorem uses a metod called "Successive Approximations", you can take a look on this.
However, if $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ is continuos, by the Mean-Value Inequality we obtain that $f$ is locally-Lipschitz, thus there is a neighborhood of $(t_{0},x_{0})$, such that $f$ is Lipschitz. Thus, by Picard-Lindelöf theorem there exist a unique solution in this neighborhood that has initial condition $(t_{0},x_{0})$.
Hence, the condition of $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ to be continuos, comes from the nescessity of $f$ beeing Lipschitz in a neighborhood of $(t_{0},x_{0})$.

As peE_ pointed out Picard-Lindelöf theorem requires Lipschitz continuity for the unique existence of the solution. If the function is not Lipschitz continuous then such existence is not guaranteed. An example is
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = -2\sqrt{|y|}$$
which has multiple solutions for $(x_0,y_0) = (0,0)$
$$y = \begin{cases}x^2, &x<0\\-x^2, &x\geq 0\end{cases}\quad\text{or}$$
$$y = 0$$
